# Drupal 7 Views Multiple Contextual Filters

Tags: filter, drupal-7, view, organic-groups

I'm running Drupal 7 with Organic Groups. I cloned the "OG all user group content" view added an Entity Reference to it to be used as a field in one of my content types. My question is:

**How can I use an additional contextual filter (Content Type) so that I can add an Argument to the Entity Reference field?**

Entering the content type name isn't working: 1/article for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the answer from:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53861/how-to-show-nodes-of-a-content-type-using-contextual-filters-as-filters

Adding "Content Type" contextually typically requires a Node ID however; using PHP Code you can simply add:

```
return TRUE;
```

and this will allow you to enter the content type name (the physical name; i.e. OpenLayers Location field is named Location but the physical path is ol_locator_location).

Answer (score -1):

When you edit the view in the Advanced link, you can see "Contextual Filter"; there you can add the field you added to the content type.

Comment: Adding another contextual filter isn't allowing an argument to be called by the Entity Reference field.

Comment: Also, the field is being generated by the View. I need to filter this view by Content Type in addition to group.